# compare values of an array, with the key of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

As the question indicates, I need to compare the values of an array of this type `[1,2,3]`, with the values of a key of an array of objects `[{id: 1, name: 'jhon'}, {id: 2 , name: 'max'}]` in this case I want to compare it with the value of the id key, I write the following example of what I need:

if I have this array of objects:

```
[
   {
      id: 1
      name: 'jhon'
   },
   {
     id: 2,
     name: 'max'
   },
   {
     id: 3,
     name: 'fer'
   }
]
```

and I have this array:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to compare them and obtain the values that are not present in the array of objects, in the previous example the values 4 and 5 are not present in the array of objects, so I need to obtain a new array or the same, but with the values that do not they were, `[4,5]`

**NOTE:** this should also work if I have an array, only with numbers that are not present, for example `[8,9]`, they should return those same values.

**EDIT:** it is possible to obtain in a new array those values that are only present in the array of objects. For example, with the arrays of the previous code:

```
[{id: 1, name: 'jhon'}, {id: 2, name: 'max'}, {id: 3, name: 'fer'}]
```

now this array would have the following values `[1,4,5]` with the previous answers I get the following array `[4,5]` what is correct. how can I get the values `[2,3]` in a new array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter` and `find`

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 1,name: 'jhon'},{id: 2,name: 'max'},{id: 3,name: 'fer'}]
let arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let result = arr2.filter(o => !arr1.find(x => x.id === o));

console.log(result);
```

---

**Update:** This is basically the reverse of the first example. You filter the `arr2` and check if the id exists on `arr1`. Then, use `map` to return the `id`

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 1,name: 'jhon'},{id: 2,name: 'max'},{id: 3,name: 'fer'}]
let arr2 = [1,4,5];

let result = arr1.filter(o => !arr2.find(x => x === o.id)).map(o=>o.id);

console.log(result);
```

Doc: [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: great! it helped me a lot

Comment: @FeRcHo Happy to help. I also added the answer to new question update.

Answer (score 2):

Create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the ids of `arr1` using [`Array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Then [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) `arr2` by checking if the Set [has](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) the number:

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"name":"jhon"},{"id":2,"name":"max"},{"id":3,"name":"fer"}];
const arr2 = [1,2,3,4,5];
const arr3 = [1, 5];

const difference = (arr1, arr2, key) => {
  const arr1Values = new Set(key ? arr1.map(({ [key]: v }) => v) : arr1);

  return arr2.filter((n) => !arr1Values.has(n));
};

// array of primitives and array of objects
console.log(difference(arr1, arr2, 'id'));

// two arrays of primitives 
console.log(difference(arr3, arr2));
```

Comment: great has helped me a lot, now that I'm just learning javascripts, add one more detail to my question I hope you can help me thanks

Answer (score 2):

*You can use filter to check if id property of element in arr2  matches to the current element in arr2*

```
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"name":"jhon"},{"id":2,"name":"max"},{"id":3,"name":"fer"}];

const arr2 = [8,9];
var diffArray = arr2.filter(x => !arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length);
console.log(diffArray);
```

**Answer**
[ 8,9 ]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.filter()` and `.includes()`:

```js
let arr1 = [{id: 1,name: 'jhon'},{id: 2, name: 'max'},{id: 3,name: 'fer'}],
    arr2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let result = (
    ids => arr2.filter(n => !ids.includes(n))
)(arr1.map(({id}) => id));

console.log(result);
```

**Description:**

- Create a new array by extracting only ids from first array using `.map()`.
- Filter elements using `.filter()` and `.includes()` to filter only those elements of second array that doesn't exists in newly created array.

**Docs:**

- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [`Object Destructuring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring)
- [`Arrow Functions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a set with the given ids and then delete the ones of the object. Later return the array with the leftover ids.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'jhon' }, { id: 2, name: 'max' }, { id: 3, name: 'fer' }],
    ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    result = Array.from(data.reduce((s, { id }) => (s.delete(id), s), new Set(ids)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```