# ES5 filter inside filter

Tags: javascript

How is this working? I am having a hard time understand this.

```js
const arr1 = [{"id":1,"name":"jhon"},{"id":2,"name":"max"},{"id":3,"name":"fer"}];
    
const arr2 = [8, 9];
var diffArray = arr2.filter(x => !arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length);
console.log(diffArray);
```

Comment: It is just checking if 8 and 9 are not present as id key in arr1, if not then it returns those array values. If you change any of the object's id to 8, you will see that only 9 is returned then and vice-versa.

Comment: `!arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length` -> `!arr1.some(y => y.id === x)` would be more efficient as it terminates iteration of the array after the first successful match.

Comment: what is length doing?@palaѕн

Comment: Just FYI, it's poor code. The inner `filter` should be `!arr1.some(y => y.id === x)` or `arr1.every(y => y.id !== x)` so it stops as soon as it knows the answer.

Comment: This is an answer from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49697279/compare-values-of-an-array-with-the-key-of-an-array-of-objects

Comment: but what is .length doing @T.J.Crowder

Comment: @RohanSingh https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length

Comment: @RohanSingh: If the filtered length is 0, the result is falsy and the outer `filter` leaves it out of the result array. If the filtered length is anything else, the result is truthy and the outer filter puts the entry in the filtered array.

Comment: `.length` returns the number of elements from `arr1` That remain after it has been filtered. The `!` coerces that number into a boolean and negates it, meaning that a length of 0 becomes `true` and any length greater than 0 becomes `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.
Code `x => some_code` is called an arrow function and can be translated to: `function(x) {return some_code}`
Basically what is done here is that `arr2.filter()` will return all elements of said `arr2` that pass the condition. Condition here is, that the **length** of "filtered" `arr1` must be zero (meaning, that the match was not found). Length of array as numerical value can be used as true/false and can be negated with `!`. That's whats going on here:

```
arr1.filter(y => y.id === x)          // means, give me elements of arr1, that are the same as in array 2
arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length   // means, the length of said array of elements
!arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length  // means, if length == 0 make it true and if more than 0 -> make it false
```

Answer (score 4):

Simplified,

```js
const arr1 = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "jhon"
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "max"
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "fer"
}];

const arr2 = [8, 9];

var diffArray = arr2.filter(x => {
  let elementsOfArray2PresentInArray1 = arr1.filter(y => {
    return y.id === x
  });

  if (elementsOfArray2PresentInArray1.length > 0) {
    return false
  } else {
    return true;
  }
  //`return !length;` will  return false if length > 0
});

console.log(diffArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or even shorter ;)

```
let diffArray = arr2.filter(x => arr1.filter(y => y.id === x).length > 0 ? false : true)
```